# Will someone get a reward if they helped someone memorize the Quran?

Tags: quran, reward, quran-memorization

As-Salamu alaikum brothers and sisters, I'd like to know... If you bought a Quran to your son, and your son memorized the Quran only throughout that Quran, will the father also get the same reward for memorizing the Quran? Jazakum Allah khayran...

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily the same reward as your son but you will have a part in it, insha Allah:

> Whoever intercedes for a good cause **will have a reward therefrom**; and
>   whoever intercedes for an evil cause will have a burden therefrom. And
>   ever is Allah , over all things, a Keeper.
>
> <sub>[Surah Nisa':85](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=4&verse=85)</sub>

And Allah knows best

Comment: Ah thank you brother, but remember that wa alaikum alsalam is fardh, and in this case I'm the son lol.

Comment: @thatonedodobird Salutations are disliked in this site, both in the questions and answers. Anyway, Walaikum Assalam brother :)